# How to keep a track of what color the code as assigned to the different categories within a column grouped by some column,?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

```
prog_rev_df.groupby('L2Discipline').Total.plot(kind='line')
```

[image]

I have shared the above code and its output, what I wish to accomplish is how can I keep track of what color it has assigned to the categories within L2Discipline ? Is there a way to create a legend ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=plot#pandas.DataFrame.plot  refer to the legend attribute

Comment: @Naveed I tried doing that, but unable to make it work. The L2Discipline column is of type object and Total is float.

Answer (score 0):

```
prog_rev_df.groupby('L2Discipline').Total.plot(kind='line',legend=prog_rev_df['L2Discipline'].any())
```

This is the fix to my issue. It is ugly but it works.